# Why am I not able to destroy the file using root.destroy in Tkinter using Pycharm on Ubuntu?

Tags: tkinter, pycharm

I am unable to exit the window, even after writing the command `root.destroy`.
The software I am using is Pycharm.
Tkinter is used on Ubuntu 18.04.

This is for creating a dialogue music player box.

```
subMenu.add_command(label="Open new project")
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit",command=root.destroy)
```

I expect the window to terminate, but it does not terminate.
Rather the window box remains idle...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: is your mainframe named `root`?

Comment: Yes, mainframe is named as root. Thanks BTW. I got the answer while I just experimenting myself.